# AWS ECS target group deregistration on deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

Everytime I try to deploy my new app as a service in ECS, the deployment fails due to target deregistration.

```
January 02, 2024 at 15:53 (UTC-6:00)    service plm-service deregistered 1 targets in target-group plm-TG   13ad0182-8c6a-42dd-82a6-743eb36bc904
January 02, 2024 at 15:53 (UTC-6:00)    (service plm-service, taskSet ecs-svc/5303646216513444271) has begun draining connections on 1 tasks.   287b1f3f-a604-4fbe-9e07-437205f45f55
January 02, 2024 at 15:53 (UTC-6:00)    service plm-service deregistered 1 targets in target-group plm-TG   d1c79a20-1ae1-439d-8f50-6bb6dd558955
January 02, 2024 at 15:53 (UTC-6:00)    service plm-service has stopped 1 running tasks: task b4a7031769c34f4aa54260672fade3c2. 09ac144b-6a0d-4a1a-a2a7-e06c24638ab3
January 02, 2024 at 15:53 (UTC-6:00)    service plm-service port 8091 is unhealthy in target-group plm-TG  due to (reason Request timed out).   0b52d773-26bb-44bd-9fcb-d5c9cdc61eea
January 02, 2024 at 15:51 (UTC-6:00)    service plm-service deregistered 1 targets in target-group plm-TG   4b28f2a0-a141-4816-9886-c875dfaf6a56
```

- This application is spring boot based and is sharing an RDS instance with another app. All my other apps running on flask deploy perfectly. In my application logs everything looks fine but the deployment keeps failing.
- Running on port 8091

Comment: That's not the reason it is failing, it is a symptom of some other failure. You need to look in the application logs to see if the service is failing to start, and look at the load balancer to see if health checks are failing.

Comment: The task logs of the application look normal and it looks like the app is starting up normally. Is there anywhere else I can look to dive deeper into this issue.

Comment: Is there a load balancer? If so, are the load balancer health checks failing?